# redirect google dynamic page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have my websites made with dynamic pages which uses a hashtag in de URL.
This makes the site a sort of one page layout.

Example
**http://www.mydomain.nl/#index.php/artikel/contact**

Google finds all these pages as single pages which works nice, but when someone click in google on the link it will go to:

Example
**http://www.mydomain.nl/index.php/artikel/contact** (no hashtag)

When people come in with no hashtag the other links won't work.

Is there a way i can modify the incoming visitors to the page with the hashtag?
So when the visitor click on other links my structure still works.
Thank you already for your time

Answer (score 0):

I can't alter how Google generates the search URIs but I do know how to do the redirect

The browser drops the #tag in its URI request so valid `http://www.mydomain.nl/#index.php/artikel/contact`, etc., generate a "`GET /`" request, but `http://www.mydomain.nl/index.php/artikel/contact` generates a "`GET /index.php/artikel/contact`" request.  Hence you need to rewrite such requests as follows, using a `DOCROOT/.htaccess`

```
Options       +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond   !-f
RewriteCond   !-d
RewriteRule   ^.+             /#$0              [R=302,L,NE]
```

The regexp needs to be a + (1 or more) repeat, so as not to match a "GET /"

This way, the server will bounce back a temporary redirect back to the browser to go to the correct anchor on the home page.

Comment: That looks like a good solution. But two problems. 1. When you come in on the main url like mydomain.com it also put some characters in it, and now i get just %23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23 between it. Any idea of these 2 points?

Comment: Oops, Forgot the NE flag.  Without this, the rewrite engine converts # to %23 which gets passed back to the server and loops.  See fix.

Comment: Hi TerryE, thank you again for your time. The problem with %23 is fixed, but there are some things which don't work. All links to CSS and images are not working anymore... This is because it thinks it is on mydomain.com/#images etc. Which is ofcourse mydomain.com/images. Do know a solution for this?

Comment: Yup, you only want to do the rule if the URI doesn't map to an existing directory or file as per changes :-)

Comment: He TerryE, thank you again for the edit, and sorry for my late reply... when i use the code above i get a Internal Server Error... can i get your help one more time? :D